# UICollectionView reload() issue with Focus state got out of sync in tvOS 15.4 and above

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, uicollectionview, tvos

In my application I have a ViewController, In that view controller I have two CollectionViews - CollectionViewA and CollectionViewB in vertically format. And basically I have a design like calendar. In CollectionViewA - Displays the informations like, S.No, Image and favourite/unfavourite options. In CollectionViewB - Displays the program informations. So when I click the favourite option I'm reloading the collectionviews so that the collection view will get reload and update the informations in UI for favourite/unfavourite icon appearance.
So this is how the functionality works.

Now what happens is, this functionality works properly till tvOS 15.2. When we do the same functionality in 15.3 and above, there is an CollectionView scroll issue (i.e) when I click favourite for the item in row number 10 then after collectionview.reload() it automatically moves to the position from 10 to 5 or 3.

This automatic scroll issue is happening with the below error which is noted in log console.

> Collection view focus state got out of sync. Expected (null) to be the
> current managed subview but found <MyApp.CollectionViewCell:
> 0x114517ad0; baseClass = UICollectionViewCell; frame = (0 6532; 270
> 126); opaque = NO; tintColor = UIExtendedGrayColorSpace 0 0; layer =
> <CALayer: 0x28339ab00>>.

Let me know if anyone can help me out from this issue!!!

Comment: Hi @Chandru, did you able to find the solution of this?

Comment: Hi, i am also facing the same issue. If you find any solution please post. Thanks

Comment: I just experienced this in the iOS 16 simulator